# Null-recurrence of a random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

In a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ starting at $0$, with probability 1/3 we go +2, with probability 2/3 we go -1. Please prove that all states in this Markov Chain are null-recurrent.

Thoughts: it is clear all states are inter-communicating, all with periodicity 3, therefore proving state 0 is null-recurrent is enough.

1. null-recurrence
   [image]
   [image]
2. One lengthy solution for simple random walk and null-recurrence
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. Where do I get stuck with 2/3, 1/3 unsymmetric random walk?
   Cannot find a series expansion that simplifies the binomial form of $P_{ij}(s)$

Comment: @JonathanChristensen I can prove that in a symmetric random walk, all states are null-recurrent, by using the generating function and series expansion, my solution is too long to be posted.

Comment: What form do you get for $P_{ij}(s)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $$P_{ij}(s) = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{3n}{n}(2/3)^{2n}(1/3)^{n}$$

Comment: The generating function for $3n\choose n$ is $f(x)=\sum_0^{\infty}{3n\choose n}x^n$. What you have written is $f(4/27)$. Some expressions for $f$ are given at http://oeis.org/A005809 - I do not know whether any of them will be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $0$ were transient, then the total number $N$ of visits to $0$ is a geometric random variable
with $p=\mathbb{P}_0(T_0=\infty)>0$ (probability of escape). That's because each excursion from $0$ is independent, 
with probability $p$ of successfully escaping. In particular, the expected number of visits is 
finite: $\mathbb{E}(N)=1/p<\infty$.

On the other hand,
$$\mathbb{E}(N)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{(X_n=0)}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n(0,0)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {3n\choose n}\left({1\over 3}\right)^n \left({2\over 3}\right)^{2n}=\infty.$$
You can show  this sum is infinite by using Stirling's formula to show that
$${3n\choose n}\left({1\over 3}\right)^n \left({2\over 3}\right)^{2n}\sim {c\over \sqrt{n}}.$$ Therefore, the state $0$ is  not  transient, so it is recurrent.

---

There are a number of ways to show that state $0$ is null. In your problem, put $x=y=0$ in (5.2) from Section 5.5 of *Probability: Theory and Examples (2nd edition)* by Richard Durrett to get:

$${1\over n}\sum_{m=1}^n p_m(0,0) \to {\mathbb{P}_0(T_0<\infty)\over \mathbb{E}_0(T_0)}.\tag{5.2}$$

Also  $p_m(0,0)\to0$ as $m\to \infty$, implies that the left hand side in (5.2) goes to zero as well, hence $\mathbb{P}_0(T_0<\infty)/\mathbb{E}_0(T_0)=0$. 
Since $\mathbb{P}_0(T_0<\infty)>0$ we conclude that $\mathbb{E}_0(T_0)=\infty$.

Comment: $$E(N) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot f_n(0,0)$$ where $f_n(0,0)$ denotes probability of __first__ return to 0, we cannot use $p_n(0,0)$ because it causes multi-counting. To grasp $f_n(0,0)$ one way is to grasp its generating function $F(0,0)$ by exploiting its relation with $P(0,0)$ - the generating function of $p_n(0,0)$, so either I misunderstood your point or I have to disagree with you. Though the result I know is that 0 is null-recurrent.

Comment: The formula in your comment is wrong. The left hand side is the expected number of visits to zero, while the right hand side is the expected number of trials until the first return to zero. These are totally different.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted, to prove null-recurrence of states we need to show that expected time until return is infinite while possibility of eventual return is positive. I see we are talking about different things.

Comment: We are not talking about different *things*, but using different *methods of proof*. You don't need generating functions to show that a state is recurrent vs transient, or positive vs null. (My solution only does the first one).

Comment: yes. If you could help with the null-ness then it would be great coz that's mainly where i get stuck.

Comment: Maybe later this afternoon, I've got to run to class now.

Comment: This is a useful theorem, I don't have the book but is there a proof for this theorem somewhere?

Comment: You can find a free copy of the book at http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/205A/index.html

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I recently came across a question similar to this where the steps of the random walk are given by P(X=3)=4/7 and the P(X=-4)=3/7. Since the expected value of each step of the walk is 0, I think this implies this walk is recurrent in one dimension. However, by the above formula for E(N) in Byron's answer, the series is convergent using sterling's formula, which seems to imply that the expected number of returns to 0 is finite? What is going on in this case?

Comment: "by the above formula for E(N) in Byron's answer, the series is convergent" No it is not. And note that your post is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to show $0$ is null-recurrent.

To get back to $0$, you have to do two $-1$s for every $+2$. So you have to take $3n$ steps, for some $n$, of which $n$ are $+2$s and $2n$ are $-1$s. The number of ways to do this is $3n\choose n$, and the probability of any one of these ways to get back to zero is $(1/3)^n(2/3)^{2n}$. So, now you know the probability of being at $0$ after $m$ steps.

I was going to say that this allows you to calculate the expected number of steps to get back to zero, but then I realized that some of the ways to get back after, say, $6$ steps include ways where you were already back after $3$ steps, so some adjustment in the formulas will be necessary to take this into account. So this is more of a suggestion as to how to proceed than it is a complete outline of a procedure.

Anyway, with some luck you'll be able to turn this into a proof that the expected time of return to $0$ is infinite, and then adjust the argument as necessary to show that every state is null-recurrent.

Comment: I see your point and in fact I wan to post my solution (very long) for the problem of symmetric (1/2-1/2) random walk, then I can tell you where do I get stuck. But please wait for a while.

Comment: I have edited the question adding a solution to the 1/2-1/2 random walk example. Please help if you can. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To treat the double counting problem as you said, one way is to calculate the probability of __first__ return and its generating function $F_{0,0}$, (by exploiting Markov property and derive a relation with $G_{0,0}$)

Answer (score 2):

One shall know that statement (not so obvious btw) :

> for an irreducible chain $E \colon $ there exists a stationnary
> distribution $\iff \exists i \in E$ such that $i$ is positive
> recurrent $\iff  \forall i \in E$, $i$ is positive recurrent.

Here, I want to prove that the chain you mentionned can't have a stationary distribution. Of course, here I'm proving that the chain is not positive recurrent, but a simple argument proves that the chain is not transient.

It would be by using the ***difference equations***. Your case is certainly not straight forward (as the length of the other answers suggest). So for the sake of understanding the method I'll simply consider the normal random walk ( $ P_{i,i+1} = \frac 1 2 = P_{i,i-1}$ ).

Let's assume that for the classic random walk, there exists a stationary distribution. Then it satisfies $$\forall j \in E :  \pi_j = \sum_{i \in E} \pi_i P_{i,j} = \frac 1 2 \pi_{j-1} + \frac 1 2  \pi_{j+1}$$

and we know how to solve such equations (difference equations). The answer is given by $$ \pi_j =  a + bj $$ with constants $a,b$. However, because of the "boundary" conditions :
$$\pi_j > 0, \forall j \implies b = 0, a > 0 $$
$$ \#E = \infty \implies \forall j, \pi_j \neq a > 0  $$

thus yielding that $ \pi $ does not exist.

Comment: I am stuck on a similar problem. Would you mind explaining how did you get the boundary conditions? I don't understand that part.

Comment: @codelearner, The two boundary conditions are the two final maths line. Both stand for the fact that you cannot have an infinite amount of strictly positive terms in the stationnary distribution; this yield that $b$ cannot be strictly positive, because whatsoever value it would take, there exists a $j$ such that it would be a problem. And recursively you do it for terms with lower degree (here there is only one term, the constant term $a$, and the idea is the same). Please let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding it :( . Would these boundary conditions be universal for any kind of such problem? and does this $\# E=\infty$ mean that there is infinite states in the state space E?

Comment: @codelearner I think it is easier if you post another question with your specific problem if you have not yet done that :) however, to answer the question you asked here: they are called boundary condition because just like for differential equations, the initial state is the only available information that we have to chose the constants. Here, the domain is infinite, so the boundary condition are in a sense the limits at $\pm \infty$. This is what we use here: since the state space is infinite, it restricts the possible constants.

Comment: In other words, the difference equation, and its solution is universal. But depending on the problem (what state space, the initial starting point...), you would get different boundary conditions, and hence a different solution. Here, the solution does not exist BECAUSE the state space is inifnite. The state space would be inside of a compact, we would get a much easier solution (that is a classic problem).