# Recurrence of random walks in terms of the mean of each step.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I am looking for a hint for the following exercise of Kannan's book 
'An introduction to stochastic processes'.

> Let $\{Y_n\}_n$ be a collection of i.i.d random variables in
>   $\mathbb{Z}$ with finite mean, define $X_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k$.
>   Prove that $X_n$ is recurrent if and only if $\mathbb{E}[Y_1]=0$.

I tried to follow as in '[Null-recurrence of a random walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285377/null-recurrence-of-a-random-walk)'. But I found it hard to do it as there are infinite possibilities for each step.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest way to prove this is via the strong law of 
large numbers in one direction, and the Chung-Fuchs theorem in the 
other. See the bottom half of page 166 in the 4th edition of 
*Probability: Theory and Examples* by Richard Durrett.

The book
is freely available online at [Durrett's website](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html) (click on the
link that says Version 4.1)